# ExtJS4 Transform Combobox onchange() event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4

I have a transform `ComboBox` in extjs4:

```
<script>   

Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

        var transformed = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
            typeAhead: true,
            transform: 'DisplayListID',
            forceSelection: true
        });
    });
  </script>



 <select  id="DisplayListID" onChange="change();">
      <option> ...

    </select>
```

ExtJS successfully transform my HTML `select` into a `ComboBox` but when I select an element, the `onChange` event is not fired.

How can I bind the javascript function `change()` to my transform `CombBox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a ExtJs change event by adding a listener to the combobox :

```
listeners: {
    change: change
}
```

where the second *change* is your function.

Answer (score 3):

Lorenz is right, you should use [change listener](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-cfg-listeners), however if you are trying to **convert several combos** at the same time and those combos already have defined functions you will need to manually link each new transformed combo with its handler method and this could be a real nightmare. You can however **subclass [ComboBox](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox) control** and let it **handle the method linkage automatically**, for this you must take into account that original 'select' gets removed after ComboBox control gets initialized. So you must get sure to keep a reference to the target method before calling the parent ComboBox init method, otherwise you will not be able to get it, something like:

```
initComponent: function() {
    var me = this,
        transform = me.transform,
        transformSelect,
        transformMethod;

    // Check if transform id has been supplied
    if(transform) {        
        // Attempt to retrieve target select from the DOM
        transformSelect = Ext.getDom(transform);
        // Get sure select node exists 
        if (transformSelect) {
            // Keep a reference to target method
            transformMethod = transformSelect.onchange;
        }
    }

    // Now that we have the method info
    // Allow ComboBox init method to replace original
    // select tag with ExtJs Control
    me.callParent(arguments);

    // Bind change event with original handler method
    me.on('change', transformMethod, me);
}
```

I've created a full **working example** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/overlordhammer/6aLwS/3/). I hope you find it useful.